# ARP Tables on Windows vs Linux

Tags: linux, windows, arp, multicast

I noticed on Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, and Windows 7 that IP multicast groups joined by a computer are recorded in the ARP table as static addresses automatically. However, the same does not seem to hold true for the ARP tables on the Cent OS and Ubuntu servers I've been referencing. I was wondering if this was an oddity of Windows, or if there was a way to enable similar behavior in a Linux environment that is not turned on by default?